# iOS App starts very slow and stalls in ImageLoaderMachO::loadCodeSignature

Tags: ios

i am developing a Swift based App for iOS 8.3 and i observed that the App starts very very slow and seems to stall in the App loading process. The App slows donwn *before* any of my code is executed. As matter of fact, only one thread is active, only 60k memory are used, the CPU is not busy.  See attached Screenshot.

The App waits for about 20-30 seconds and continues as expected without any exceptions or error messages.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Do you use any Embedded framework or cocoa pods? Does it happen with Add-Hoc provision profile or with Dev as well ?

Comment: I'm seeing the same issue. When it happens my device is connected to a wifi network that doesn't have internet connectivity. When I'm not connected to Xcode, the watch dog kills the app. Does anyone know if there's a risk of having this behavior happening in a production build? Or does it only happen for development builds?

Comment: did you guys every figure this issue out? I'm having this issue with all third-party apps, app-store and personally built ones.

Comment: It's happens on my device when it's connected to wi-fi and I'm trying to install-launch it through xCode. If I switch off the wifi, the app starts immediately.

Comment: PS. my wifi has internet connectivity but it is a corporate wifi, that has some restrictions. Can't test on cellular or any other wifi.

Comment: Just want to post the link to related issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33044062/build-lags-for-a-full-minute-on-performing-install-actions
Still there is no solution.

Comment: I'm seeng this issue only on one particular iPhone, but another one doesn't have it. Same iOS versions, same network.

Answer (score 0):

All this happens because there are Security checks added by the apple.
This is not applicable for not only iOS devices but applicable for all MAC devices as well.

For any change in files there will be security, signature checks gets performed.
Depending on the machine(iPhone/Mac), internet speed it takes times to get completed.
Any subsequent call to same (no recompile, modified) file does not observe this issue.