# Build lags for a full minute on "Performing Install Actions"

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, build

Today, my builds suddenly started taking a long time to install & launch on my iPad (using XCode 7).  During the "Performing Install Actions" phase, it hangs for about a minute, and then when the launch screen shows on the device, it takes about another minute for the app to launch.  After the app launches, it runs normally without any issues.

I've restarted Xcode, cleaned the app, deleted build folders, deleted DerivedData, restarted OSX, restarted iOS, deleted the app from my iPad, and even upgraded iOS on the iPad to 9.0.2.

Edit: This issue originally seemed to be specific to the iPad Mini 3 I was using; it didn't happen on the iPhones I'm testing with.  Now, after the weekend, it's happening on an iOS 8.4 iPhone 5s that I'm also developing on.

Edit 2:  This was happening sporadically yesterday and it now seems to have cleared itself up, on all my devices.  Still no idea what steps to take to fix this if it happens, though.

Edit 3:  It continues to happen, but much more rarely.

Comment: This happens consistently for me on 10.11.3 and xcode 7.2.1 (and .3 beta). It started after my upgrade to el capitan. Rebooting device and and turning off wifi on device have no effect. If anyone has other solutions or things to try please mention them here. Thanks.

Comment: I've just had same issue for one particular iPhone, but another one had no issues at all. Same iOS version on both of them, both connected to the same wifi.

Comment: And there is another one issue that seems related to the subject: I can't register for remote notifications on the device that has "Performing Install Actions" issue. There is a question that is strongly related to the subject: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30589875/ios-app-starts-very-slow-and-stalls-in-imageloadermacholoadcodesignature It seems that something going wrong with code signing.

Comment: This issue disappears if I turn off the wifi on the device

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've been dealing with this same thing, but **connecting the phone to WiFi** seems to unblock my installs. Who knows why... but give that a shot if you're still running into this issue.

Comment: That might make sense; I've been developing connected to an external device a lot of the time.  I'll try this next time it happens!

Comment: Yes, I just got this while developing with an external device connected to Wifi.  Turning wifi off immediately fixed it!   (and I didn't have any problems subsequently connected to a standard wifi network, as opposed to the external device)

Answer (score 1):

I recently ran into this problem and resolved it by restarting the device. I have no idea of what the cause is so I am reticent to suggest this is a universal solution but it did work for me once in a row.

Answer (score 1):

**Fix :** Turn off iPhone wifi. restart it and install the app now. Now you turn on the wifi. and it works. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, but for me the app wouldn't launch at all. This might have been happening because I was connected to a WiFi that didn't have internet access. **Changing to a WiFi with internet access solved the problem for me**. It started happening suddenly for me as well, so not sure what triggers it. I've now changed back to the WiFi without internet access, and it seems to work again.

Answer (score 0):

I met this problem in Company, but not at home, when debugging on device.
So if you are working under a company WIFI, just **Changing WiFi to Internet Access** will solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem just now.

What does **NOT** work for me:

- Restart Xcode
- Clean the project
- Unpair and reconnect the device
- (Re)connect to wifi

What **DOES** work for me:

- Restart the device and build again

Answer (score 0):

Another possible cause is low disk space on your Mac. Make sure your mac has enough space - I was running with 13mB space remaining... This will impact cacheing etc. and will cause delays on your build.

Answer (score 0):

I have this issue when my Apple Watch are on me. Maybe some problems with paired devices.